# homomorphism $\mathrm{GL}(1,4)$ to $\mathrm{GL}(2,2)$ which is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, permutations

Show that there is homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}(1,4)$ to $\mathrm{GL}(2,2)$, where $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ denotes the general linear group, ie invertible $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_k$, such that it corresponds to the inclusion of $A_3$ in $S_3$ and it is injective. Furthermore, show that the same map is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{F}_4$ to all $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

I'm not sure what "corresponds to the inclusion" means? Could someone help me? I just need a map but not sure where to start.

Comment: The exercise asks you to give isomorphisms $f_1 \colon GL(1,4) \to A_3$, $f_2 \colon GL(2,2) \to S_3$ and an injective group homomorphism $\varphi \colon GL(1,4) \to GL(2,2)$, such that $\varphi = f_1 \circ i \circ f_2^{-1}$, where $i$ is the inclusion $A_3 \subset S_3$. Draw a diagram for better visualization of the situation.

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense, but I still do not understand what $i$ means in terms of mappings?

Comment: @Marktmeister, Is not $\varphi=f_2^{-1} \circ i \circ f_1$?

Comment: @M.A. SARKAR You are correct. I am really bad at these kind of things. :-)

Comment: @mandella $i$ is just the inclusion $A_3 \subset S_3$, which means that $i(x) = x$ for any $x \in A_3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element $x$ in $\mathrm{GL}(1,4)$ is just a non zero element in $F_4$.

The main idea is to consider $F_4$ as a vector space of dimension 2 over $F_2$.

Then multiplication by $x$ is a $F_2$ linear map $F_4\to F_4$, and therefore an element in $\mathrm{GL}(2,F_2)$. But this application is also defined if $x=0$.

Summing up, the map $\mu :F_4\to L(F_4)$ , where $L(F_4)$ is   the ring of $F_2-$linear maps $F_4\to F_4$, defined by $\mu(x).y=x.y$ is a ring homomorphism from $F_4$ to the ring of $F_2-$linear maps $F_4\to F_4$.

Comment: What about $A_3$ and $S_3$? I don't see where they come in here.

Comment: If $x\not=0$ is in $F_4$, then $x^3=1$. $S_4$ is just the group of permutation of the 4 elements in $F_4$. The multiplication by $x$ is a permutation of the 4 elements in $F_4$, whence a map $A_3=Z/3Z\to S_4$.

Comment: So we get a map $A_3 \to S_4$? So how is this the 'correspondence' thing to the inclusion of $A_3$ in $S_3$? Sorry I am genuinely confused because so many things are going on

Comment: In fact, you can see that $G(2,2)=S_3$, and $A_3<S_3$ is the unique subgrup with 3 elments